# Creating callback function with closure on a parameter, without "may outlive borrowed value" or "this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`"

Tags: rust, closures

I would like to create a callback function that has access to the argument `instanceContext`, but I am not sure how to fix the code.
The failing code is `instanceContext.instances.len()`.

I have tried using lifetimes, move, Rc, Arc, Box, RefCell, but nothing seems to work.

The goal is to have multiple Instances which will have callbacks that will make it possible for one Instance to call/modify another Instance, through the InstanceContext.

During my experimentation I've been getting the following errors:

- may outlive borrowed value
- borrowed value does not live long enough
- closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable
- this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`

```
use wasmtime::*;

struct InstanceContext {
    id: i32,
    instances: Vec<Instance>,
}

fn main() {
    let store = Store::new(&Engine::default());
    let mut instanceContext = InstanceContext { id: 5, instances: Vec::new() };
    let _callback = createCallback(&store, &mut instanceContext);
}

fn createCallback(store: &Store, instanceContext: &mut InstanceContext) -> wasmtime::Func {
    let f = Func::wrap(&store, || {
        println!("Number of instances: {}", instanceContext.instances.len());
    });
    f
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide the compiler error message or an actual reproduction case so it's hard to know whether the diagnostic achieved by just thinking about things is the correct one, but to me it looks like this would be the solution:

```rust
fn main() {
    let store = Store::new(&Engine::default());
    let mut instanceContext = Rc::new(RefCell::new(InstanceContext { id: 5, instances: Vec::new() }));
    let _callback = createCallback(&store, instanceContext.clone());
}

fn createCallback(store: &Store, instanceContext: Rc<RefCell<InstanceContext>>) -> wasmtime::Func {
    let f = Func::wrap(&store, move || {
        println!("Number of instances: {}", instanceContext.borrow().instances.len());
    });
    f
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! I am very grateful. The code I provided is an MWE that doesn't compile, so I am not sure what you mean? Your feedback would be useful so I can post better questions in the future.

Comment: The gold standard is something which demonstrates the specific issue on play.rust-lang.org

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. However, that particular playground doesn't support the wasmtime dependency, but maybe I can find a similar playground that does, or make an MWE without a dependency. Thanks!